# Start DateTimeField and End DateTimeField duration time Show the price.. django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I will input start `DateTimeField` and end `DateTimeField` from *Admin Panel*.

Offer price will be shown when the start time will match `now()`.

When the current time matches start `DateTimeField`, then the price will be shown as HTML.

similarly, when the end `DateTimeField` matches the current time then the offer price will be shown OFF from the HTML form.

My models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    offer_price         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    duration            = models.DurationField('duration')
    offer_price_start_date   = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    offer_price_end_date     = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def duration(self):
        return self.offer_price_end_date - self.offer_price_start_date
```

My views:

```
def product_detail(request):
    product_data = Product.objects.all()

    context = {
        'product': product_data 
    }
    
    return render(request, 'show.html', context)
```

My template `show.html`

```html
{% if product.duration %}
<a>    
  Before Price ${{ product.price }}             
</a>                                            
<a> 
    Now ${{ product.offer_price }}            
</a>  
{% endif %}
```

Comment: why you don't just filter the queryset in the view?

Comment: @Jonas I want to create but How

Answer (score 1):

You could add the current date as variable in the template (using [`timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) like the docs suggest):

```
from django.utils import timezone as tz

def product_detail(request):
    context = {
        'current_time': tz.now(),
        'product_list': Product.objects.all(),
    }
    
    return render(request, 'show.html', context)
```

and then in your template use that variable for filtering; the following code shows prices of all products, and additionally for those products that have a currently valid offer, the offer price is also shown.

```html
{% for p in product_list %}
    <a>    
      Price ${{ p.price }}             
    </a>                                            
    {% if p.offer_price_start_date <= current_time <= p.offer_price_end_date %}
    <a> 
      Offer price ${{ p.offer_price }}            
    </a>  
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I am trying different way (  p.offer_price_start_date <= current_time <= p.offer_price_start_date ) this logic and also try views & model in this logic ...
All are not working...

Comment: Only the offer period will be showing the offer price. that's are set manually by the admin panel.. 
Thanks in advance for your valuable time....

Comment: @rasel120 I corrected a small mistake in my answer: the filtering has to use start and end date `p.offer_price_start_date <= current_time <= p.offer_price_end_date`, I had used start date both times. Does it work now?